# Transferring focus from new jFrame to previous jFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two JFrames `jFrame1` and `jFrame2`,in jFrame1 there's a textfield and a button,while clicking on button jFrame2 will appear. In jFrame2 there's also a textfield and a button.I will type a name in textfield of jFrame2 and by clicking the button in it that textfield value should appear on textfield of jFrame1. But I am not getting the focus transferred to jFrame1,i tried the code,

in jFrame1

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jFrame2 abc=new jFrame2();
        abc.setVisible(true);
    }   


public void inserting(String name){
   jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();
   jTextField1.setText(name);

 }
```

in jFrame2,

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        jFrame1 abc1=new jFrame1();
       // abc1.transferFocus();  //not working

        abc1.inserting(jTextField1.getText());
        this.dispose();
    }
```

I am getting value to the method `inserting()`,but it's not getting set into the textfield. If I again give `setVisible(true)` for jFrame1 it works,but I dont want to do i in that way. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bring focus to the field, you should use `requestFocusInWindow`, however I don't think that will bring the window in question back into focus.

You could use a `WindowListener` to monitor changes that you could respond.

For example, in `jFrame1`'s `actionPerformed` handler you could

```
Frame02 frame2 = new Frame02();
frame2.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent we) {

        Frame02 frame2 = (Frame02) we.getWindow();
        jTextField1.setText(frame2.getText());

        toFront();
        jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();

    }

});

frame2.setVisible(true);
frame2.toFront();
frame2.requestFocus();
```

`jFrame1` is requesting the text from `jFrame2` cause `jFrame2` doesn't know about `jFrame1`, there's no reference to it.

In `jFrame2` you would need to add a `WindowListener` to handle the request for focus of the text field

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent we) {
        jTextField1.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: i had tried both toFront and requestFocusInWindow methods..but nothing happens.

Comment: It works even if I dont use toFront method..Can you please tell me after setting frame2.setVisible(true) what is the relevance of setting toFront again?

Comment: This could be a side effect of the second window listener, but on some systems it's possible the frame may not be brought to the front if focus remains in the first frame.  This just a nice way of safe guarding against these possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using your second frame to just take a user's input, why not switch to using a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`? You can configure this to give you a `TextField` and a `Button` and returns a String? Use this value to set the value of the `JTextField` in your first frame.

So your first method would be something like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter Value: ");
    jTextField1.setText(inputString);
}
```

I think this one would be a simpler solution instead of working with a couple of frames and switching focus in between them.

This tutorial about ["Getting the User's Input from a Dialog"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) might help you get a better picture about using Input Dialog.

Comment: your option is good,but I am trying to get a value from another jframe only.